# Given that $p>n+1$, how to prove that: $\sum_{k=1}^{p-n}\frac1{(n+1)^k}$ is less than $\frac 1n$.

Tags: inequality

Given that $p>n+1$, how to prove that:$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p-n}\frac1{(n+1)^k}$$ is less than $\frac 1n$.

I tried to show to for every value of $k$ the result is smaller than $\frac 1 {n^2}$ but it didn't work

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Do you know the closed-form formula for a geometric series?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Comment: No i don't know it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a geometric series with $$a_1 = r = \frac{1}{n + 1}$$
Applying the formula $$S_n = \frac{a_1 (1 - r^n)}{1 - r}$$
we get
$$S_{p - n} = \frac{1}{n + 1} \cdot \frac{1 - (n + 1)^{n - p}}{1 - (n + 1)^{-1}} = \frac{1 - (n + 1)^{n - p}}{n} < \frac{1}{n}$$
This assumes that $(n + 1)^{n - p} > 0.$